# How to set default keyboard for EditText

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

If I have set android keyboard as default in keyboard setting and I clicked in EditText  in my application then I am getting keyboard in english. But in my application there is an edittext to enter username. I need to show japanese soft keyboard. How to achieve this? I can long click on the edit text and set the input type as Japanese IME. can I do this programmetically without setting keyboard type explicitly? How to set default keyboard type for any particular EditText.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users choose their input method editors, not applications.  Allowing an app to change the keyboard would be a security flaw.

Comment: How is this a security flaw, exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at [InputType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html)